# PHP Regex to get a name from a url tag

Tags: php, regex

There is a lot of Regex to get links or a value from url tags `<a href` , but what about extract a value from url tags like this

```
$text = '[URL="http://google.com"]ANY THING[/URL]';
```

if i want get value `ANY THING` from this url tag , what Regex Can I use ?

Comment: Usually, PHP is *creating* the tag, or the tag is source code in the PHP file. Are you using PHP to read a page from a server?

Comment: `\[URL[^]]+\](?P<name>[^\[]+)\[\/URL\]`  https://regex101.com/r/hS0sO5/1

Comment: @JonathanM you are right , i want extract a value from source code of Script

Comment: @user3745594 please use modern solutions for BBCode, I recommend my own library https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one

```
'/\[URL[^]]+\](?P<name>[^\[]+)\[\/URL\]/'
```

But you should probably learn Why..  Here is a good tester that shows that regx at work

https://regex101.com/r/hS0sO5/1

Traditionally this is called BBcode ( builtin board code )

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode

There are full PHP implementations of this sort of thing you can use besides regx

If you want both ( optionally the url ) you can use this one

```
'/\[URL(?:\=\"(?P<url>[^"]+)\")?\](?P<name>[^\[]+)\[\/URL\]/'
```

And here is that one at work

https://regex101.com/r/hS0sO5/2

That last one does require the `"` around URL, I have seen them done with `'` or no quotes at all.

Comment: Good answer .. Thanks for your help